# How to Show/Hide Div on SelectedIndex in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="slDisThrough" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Distributed Through</label>
    <div class="col-sm-11">
        <select name="slDisThrough" id="slDisThrough" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Agent</option>
            <option value="2">Retail</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slAgentID" class="hide">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="slAgent" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Agent</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <select name="slAgent" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">Show</option>
                <option value="2">Hide</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slRetailID" class="hide">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="slRetail" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Retail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <select name="slRetail" class="form-control">
               <option value="0">-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">Hide</option>
                <option value="2">Show</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eligiable/Le3uf/1/)

```
if(document.getElementById("slDisThrough").selectedIndex == 1) {
    document.getElementById("slAgentID").style.display = ""; }
    else { document.getElementById("slAgentID").style.display = "none"; }
if(document.getElementById("slDisThrough").selectedIndex == 2) {
    document.getElementById("slRetail").style.display = ""; }
    else { document.getElementById("slRetail").style.display = "none"; }
```

I need to Show/Hide the DIVs on Selected Value, I was previously using it with JavaScript, but stuck with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you load jQuery, better use it like this:

```
$('#slDisThrough').on('change', function(){       
    if ($(this).val() == 1 ) {
        $('#slAgentID').removeClass('hide');
        $('#slRetailID').addClass('hide');      
    }

    if ($(this).val() == 2 ) {
        $('#slAgentID').addClass('hide'); 
        $('#slRetailID').removeClass('hide');        
    }
})
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/Ya6PD/)